# I can't read data from the SQLite database

Tags: android, react-native, sqlite, mobile, expo

I'm creating an application in react-native and expo with SQLite , apparently I have everything right to create the table and insert the data but when I go to read it I can't read anything.

I don't know if the problem is in creating the database and inserting the data or if it's in the code to read the data, does anyone know why?

My connection code :

```
import * as SQLite from "expo-sqlite";

const DataBase = SQLite.openDatabase({name:"db.db" , location:"default"});

export default DataBase;
```

Creating a table and inserting data :

```
import DataBase from "./SQLitedatabase";
import exerciciosData from "./exerciciosdata.json";

const CreateTable = () =>{
    DataBase.transaction((tx) =>{
        tx.executeSql(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Exercicios (id_Exercicio INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Grupo_Muscular TEXT , Descricao TEXT , Nome_Exercicio TEXT , Series TEXT , Repeticoes TEXT , Parte_Muscular TEXT )"
        );
    });
};


const InsertData = () =>{
    return new Promise((resolve , reject) =>{
        DataBase.transaction(
            tx =>{
                tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Exercicios" , [] , (tx,results) =>{
                    const contRow = results.rows.length;
                    if(contRow === 0){
                        console.log(results)
                        exerciciosData.forEach((exercicio) =>{
                            tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO Exercicios (Grupo_Muscular , Descricao , Nome_Exercicio , Series , Repeticoes , Parte_Muscular) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)" ,
                                [
                                    exercicio.Grupo_Muscular,
                                    exercicio.Descricao,
                                    exercicio.Nome_Exercicio,
                                    exercicio.Series,
                                    exercicio.Repeticoes,
                                    exercicio.Parte_Muscular
                                ] 
                            )
                        })
                    }
                });
            }
        )
    })
}
  
export { CreateTable, InsertData};
```

Code to read the data and display it (no styling yet) :

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View , Image ,TextInput , TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Ionicons from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import { useState , useEffect } from 'react';
import {initializeApp} from "firebase/app";
import {getAuth , createUserWithEmailAndPassword , signInWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged} from "firebase/auth";
import {getFirestore , collection , addDoc} from "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/firestore";
import app from "./FirebaseConfig.js"
import {authState} from './FirebaseConfig.js';
import { useUser } from './usercontext.js';
import DataBase from "../../services/SQLitedatabase.js";

const Exercicios = () =>{

    const [Musculo , setMusculo] = useState("");
    const [Exercicios , setExercicios] = useState([]);

    const ReadData = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          DataBase.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(
              "SELECT * FROM Exercicios;",
              [],
              (_, { rows }) => {
                const exerciciosArray = rows._array;
                setExercicios(exerciciosArray); // Armazena os dados no estado Exercicios
                resolve(exerciciosArray); // Resolve a promessa com os dados
              },
              (_, error) => reject(error) // erro interno em tx.executeSql
            );
          });
        });
      };

    return(
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:25 , alignSelf:"center",marginTop:15}}>Selecione o agrupamento</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize:25 , alignSelf:"center"}}>muscular desejado:</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => ReadData()} style={styles.botao}>
                <Text>Testar</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            {
                (Exercicios.length == 0)
                ?
                <View style={{flex:1 , justifyContent:"center" , alignItems:"center"}}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize:30}}>Carregando...</Text>
                </View>
                :
                <View style={{flex:1 , justifyContent:"center" , alignItems:"center"}}>
                    <Text>{Exercicios}</Text>
                </View>
            }
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    botao:{
        backgroundColor:"#e6e6e6",
        marginTop:10,
        width:300,
        height:45,
        alignSelf:"center",
        borderRadius:5,
        padding:7,
        borderWidth:1,
        borderColor:"#111111"
    }
})

export default Exercicios;
```

I've already recreated and created it in several different ways and still haven't gotten any results.